# Check if reversing a sub array make the array sorted-Python

Tags: python, algorithm, list

```
v=[1,2,3,4,8,7,6,9]
```

In the list above reversing 6,7,8 will give consecutive values. If I understand correctly, I think that is what this problem wants to find https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-reversing-sub-array-make-array-sorted/

My approach was

1. Find  lists of reversed values
2. Find which of those lists contain consecutive number.

I can't get the step2 to work. Here is my code:

```
v=[1,2,3,4,8,7,6,9]

ls=[]
# This part below will generate many lists and 1 of them will be [6,7,8]
for i in range (0,len(v)-1):
    for j in range(i+1, len(v)):
        r= v[i:j][::-1]
        ls.append(r)# this append lists not values

#Below code will check to see if any list has consecutive values
for item in ls:
    for i in range(len(item) - 1):
        if item[i] + 1 == item[i + 1]:
            if i == 0 or item[i] - 1 != item[i - 1]:
                print(item)
```

I get the following, when I was expecting [6,7,8]

```
[6, 7, 8, 4, 3]
[7, 8, 4]
[6, 7, 8, 4]
[7, 8]
[6, 7, 8]
```

Can someone kindly give me some hint? Did I interpret the original question correctly? I did not want to use the geek for geek answer.

Comment: There's no requirement of the sorted values being consecutive numbers in the linked question.

Comment: I see, what you are saying when I read "By reversing the subarray {5, 4, 3}, the array will be sorted." I assumed the numbers need to be consecutive.

Comment: Ok, numbers need not be consecutive. Also, you can just use 2 pointers to make this work. The third solution in the link should work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only looking for a single substring to reverse, you could use zip() to make consecutive value pairs comparisons. First determine the location of the first decreasing pair. Then find the location of the first increasing pair from that point on.  If you have a valid range, inverse the substring and test if the list is in order.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,8,7,6,9]

start        = next( (i for i,(v0,v1) in enumerate(zip(a,a[1:])) if v0>v1),len(a))
end          = next( (i+start+1 for i,(v0,v1) in enumerate(zip(a[start:],a[start+1:])) if v0<v1),len(a))
if end > start : a[start:end] = a[start:end][::-1]
canSort      = end > start+1 and not any( a>b for a,b in zip(a,a[1:])) # True
```

*This will process in O(n) time, as opposed to O(n^2) for nested loops.*

If you want to check for multiple substring inversions, you will need to make this into a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this ... assuming that by consecutive numbers you mean numbers that differ by one unit. You can also change the script to accommodate numbers in reverse order but not exactl orders (8 7 6) vs (9 6 4)

```
v=[1,2,3,4,8,7,6,9]

l = []
last_item =-99
for i in range(1,len(v)-1):
    if  v[i]  == v[i + 1] + 1:
        l.append(v[i])
        last_item = v[i]
    elif v[i] == last_item - 1:
        l.append(v[i])
        last_item = v[i]
print(sorted(l))
```